# Apache reverse proxy to nodejs server on CentOS 7.7 (WHM)

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, node.js

I'm trying to setup an apache reverse proxy when accessing mysite.com to 127.0.0.1:3001, by setting up a virtual host in the WHM > Apache Configuration > Include Editor > Post VirtualHost Include (all versions).

I have a subdomain api.mysite.com (php) which is working and for front mysite.com I want to use a nodejs app that's running on server on localhost:3001.

This is what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
       Require all granted
    </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
</VirtualHost>
```

It only works for front when I remove virtual host and use only this part, but then it uses reverse proxy for all, even the api.mysite.com.

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3001/
```

Comment: You need separate virtual host configurations for each domain, cf. [Apache's documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#using).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Piotr. But I found that I have to use the WHM interface for this, which will edit /etc/apache2/conf.d/includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf. So I can't edit the main conf to include other files because it will be overwritten by WHM.

Comment: Yes, but you can put two `<VirtualHost>` definitions in the same file.

Comment: I understand that I can have multiple `VirtualHost` definitions in the same file. But the main thing that confuses me, is why is this `<VirtualHost *:80>` definition ignored. And it only works when I set the proxy globally.

Comment: That probably means that WHM has defined another `<VirtualHost>` which overrides your config. Panel related questions are generally considered [off topic here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sorry, I didn't realize that WHM was off topis here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101992/discussion-between-piotr-p-karwasz-and-vstruhar).

Answer (score 0):

After a chat with Piotr, he suggested to create a conf file in the `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2/user/mysite_com.conf` and move the VirtualHost definition there, and it finally worked :)